# How to use hist() function with count data as input

Tags: r

What is the criteria for using the hist() function in R?

I have two columns of data, which looks something like this:

1 8764
2 604
3 150
4 50
5 21
6 7
7 2
8 5
10 3
11 2
12 1
14 1
16 1
17 2
18 3
20 1
23 1
24 1
25 1
28 1
29 1

When I put that into a data frame in R, and try to plot that using the hist() function, it gives me an error "x: must be numerical". How do I go about solving this?

I'm trying to get the first column on the x-axis and the second column on the y-axis.

Pardon if the question sounds stupid, its my first time using R.

Comment: It seems you make the common mistake of confusing a histogram with a barplot.

Comment: I'm required to use a histogram to show the graph, not a bar plot.

Comment: "I'm trying to get the first column on the x-axis and the second column on the y-axis." That is not a histogram. It might be possible that the second column are counts and the first column interval midpoints and if you plot this as a barplot you'd indeed get a histogram. However, this doesn't involve the `hist` fucntion.

Comment: Apologies. If I just wanted to get that data in a histogram, how would I go about doing that? Or alternatively, if I just wanted the second column put in the histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this if you absolutely *want* to use the `hist` function:

```
hist(rep(df[[1]], df[[2]]))
```

df being your data.frame (well, if I understand as Roland said in the comments that the first column might be your values and the second column your frequency counts)

**Edit** it appears that your data.frame only has one column. In this case this will work:

```
hist(rep(seq_along(df[[1]]), df[[1]]))
```

In case of presence of `NA` do this before:

```
df <- na.omit(df)
```

Comment: Tried doing that, gives me this error: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I've never used R before, so I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: i've modified my data input, it now looks like this: 'data.frame': 21 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 ...
 $ V2: int  8764 604 150 50 21 7 2 5 3 2 ...

Comment: I tried multiple options, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: hist(df$V1, df$V2)
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Comment: hist(df[[1]],df[[2]], xlim = 35, ylim = 10000)
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : invalid 'xlim' value

Comment: Gives this error: Error in seq_along(df[[1]], df[[2]]) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'seq_along' which requires 1

Comment: thanks so much! it worked!

Comment: Haleluja! Haleluja!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is `data.frame` called `df`  then just do `hist(df)`. It plots by default, of you can plot it with `plot(hist(df))`.

Comment: I tried doing that, it still gives me the same error that " 'x' must be numeric"

Comment: what is the output of `str(df)`?

Comment: 'data.frame': 21 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 21 levels "1 8764","10 3",..: 1 9 16 17 18 19 20 21 2 3 ...

Comment: then do `hist(as.numeric(df$V1))`. The error is quite self-explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: They need to fix there data import first ...

Comment: How do I fix the data import? My import code is as follows:

Comment: df <- read.csv('file.txt',header=FALSE)

Comment: @JanSila hmm, never would do such transformation like you suggest. Try this: as.numeric(factor(c(3,5,1,2,3,4), levels = c(3,5,1,2,4)))

Comment: `R` interprets values form the txt file as strings, that's why it stores them as factors, not integers. You can either cast them in R using `as.numeric` or before import for example in Excel where you make sure it is numeric and save it as `csv` and import it as `csv`.

Comment: i've imported it as a csv file, and the data now looks like this: 'data.frame': 21 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 ...
 $ V2: int  8764 604 150 50 21 7 2 5 3 2 ...

Comment: then try `hist(df$V2)` if you want histogram for those values, or as @agenis says below if the left column are your values and right is counts